# Undefined index: nid

Tags: indexing, undefined

I am having problem with my code to edit details. It is pulling the values from the table but when i click the submit button with or without changing anything I am getting

> Undefined index: .

It was working before I just added 2 more values.

I have tried to add `if(isset($_POST["value"]))` to the values but when I hit submit it shows no error but it does not update.

```
//determine if the sumbit button was pressed
if(isset($_POST["registrationSubmit"]))
{
    //get the values from the form
    $nid = $_POST["nid"];
    $fn = $_POST["fn"];
    $ln = $_POST["ln"];
    $e = $_POST["e"];
    $a = $_POST["a"];
    $c = $_POST["c"];




    //do validation
    $errorCount = 0;

    if($nid == "" || $nid== null)
    {
        $error1 = "Please enter the national ID of the Volunteer";
        $errorCount++;
    }
    else if(strlen($nid) <11)
    {
        $error1="National must be 11 characters";
        $errorCount++;
    }
    if($fn == "" || $fn== null)
    {
        $error2 = "Please enter the first name of the Volunteer";
        $errorCount++;
    }
    if($ln == "" || $ln== null)
    {
        $error3 = "Please enter the last name of the Volunteer";
        $errorCount++;
    }
    if($e == "" || $e == null)
    {
        $error4 = "Please enter the email of the Volunteer";
        $errorCount++;
    }
    if($a == "" || $a == null)
    {
        $error5 = "Please enter the address of the Volunteer";
        $errorCount++;
    }
    if($c == "" || $c == null)
    {
        $error6 = "Please enter the contact of the Volunteer";
        $errorCount++;
    }
    if($errorCount == 0)
    {
        //commonize
        $fn = strtolower($fn);

        //capitalize
        $fn = ucfirst($fn);

        //commonize
        $ln = strtolower($ln);

        //capitalize
        $ln = ucfirst($ln);

        //sanitize
        $nid = filter_var($nid,
        FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $fn = filter_var($fn,
        FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $ln = filter_var($ln,
        FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $e = filter_var($e,
        FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $a = filter_var($a,
        FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        $c = filter_var($c,
        FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);


        //include the database connection
        include("services/databaseConnection.php");

        //do update for customer
        if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($mysqli, "UPDATE Volunteer SET nationalID = ?, firstName = ?, lastName = ?, email = ?, address = ?, contact = ? WHERE VolunteerID = ?"))
        {
            // bind parameters for markers
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "isssiii",
            $nid, $fn, $ln, $e, $a, $c, $VolunteerID);

            // execute query
            mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt) or die (
            mysqli_error($mysqli));

            //close statement
            mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
        }

        //close connection
        mysqli_close($mysqli);

        echo("Volunteer Details have been updated successfully");
    }
}
```

Comment: Where does `$VolunteerID` come from in your SQL query?

Comment: from the database

Comment: this is not visible in your code.

Comment: and the `Undefined index` does not show a line number or the field of your `$_POST` which is not set?

Comment: the lines $nid = $_POST["nid"]  $fn = $_POST["fn"];  $ln = $_POST["ln"]; those three i am having the error with

Comment: So, yes, for your first issue, using `$nid = isset($_POST['nid']) ? $_POST['nid'] : NULL;` for `nid`, `fn` and `ln` seems to be a reasonable option.

Comment: You have a second issue `it shows no error but it does not update.` . You can try to check what are the values of `$nid, $fn, $ln, $e, $a, $c, $VolunteerID` just before the execution of the query. One possibility is that `$VolunteerID` is wrongly set: your snippet does not show how this var is instantiated.